# UIView animation not repeating/stopping suddenly

Tags: ios, uiview, ios5

I have a `UILabel` fading in, then using autoreverse fades out. As soon as it fades back out, the alpha immediately jumps to 1 and the animation stops.

```
arrivingLabelRed.alpha=0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:2
                      delay:1.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{
                     arrivingLabelRed.alpha=1;
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];
```

Comment: Can you provide some insight on what happens between the first and second animation?  Does arrivingLabelRed.alpha get set back to 0?

Comment: I forgot to mention this UIView animation is on a tableView cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's working the way it's supposed to.  If you want arrivingLabelRed to end with it's alpha at 0 you should set it that way in the completion block.

Answer (score 3):

Set the alpha back to 0 in your completion block:

```
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"Done!");
    arrivingLabelRed.alpha = 0;
}
```